# electron app always placed at the top with full-width and other windows should be placed under it

Tags: window, electron, screen

I am facing an issue.
I need my electron app always placed at the top with full-width and other windows should be placed under it.
How can I do this?
anyone can help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Hope this will help you [C# helper](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2016/12/set-another-applications-size-and-position-in-c/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mainWindow.maximize()` to display full width screen.

```
function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1366,
        height: 783,
        alwaysOnTop:true //display show on top
    })
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');


    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
    })
    mainWindow.maximize() //call like this way 
}
```

You can get more reference from [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions)

Comment: I have created the full width app.
but I need to control  window.
other windows should be placed under it

Comment: Rahul do you want to know if there is a way to control the windows from other running applications, and place them on the screen below your app?

Comment: I think what @RAHULDEV want is to place all the apps on the bottom of the current app. like placing the application on the top of the screen and all the other applications below it (to the bottom of the screen)

Comment: Still its mystery that what @RAHULDEV want, Are you want to create child window? let us clear